# Force HTTPS on alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I have been trying to enable HTTPS login on alfresco but it seems to be a challenge to get it working.
I can access my website via HTTPS and get the login page, but when I login with the correct credentials I get the following error :

Something's wrong with this page...
We may have hit an error or something might have been removed or deleted, so check that the URL is correct.

Alternatively you might not have permission to view the page (it could be on a private site) or there could have been an internal error. Try checking with your IT team.

If you're trying to get to your home page and it's no longer available you should change it by clicking your name on the toolbar.

I must login in HTTP then refresh my HTTPS page to be connected in HTTPS.
I have already seen what the offical doc says and tested it but it didn't work.

Has anyone an idea on how to fix the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow [the official docs on setting up SSL](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/configure-ssl-prod.html)?

Comment: Of course, it was the first thing I have done. I get the login page in HTTPS but can't log in.

Comment: Do both `/alfresco/` and `/share/` work on https?

Comment: If you're wondering if alfresco.protocol and share.protocol are set to HTTPS the yes. If this isn't what you're asking can you please clarify your question ? :)

Comment: If you go to `/alfresco/` instead of `/share/` does that work over https? Can you log into the admin console ok over https? And did you update your share config to tell it about https?

Comment: Yes it works over HTTPS. The config file alfresco-global.proprties was updated with the correct values for alfresco and share arguments (protocol, port...)
But I still can't access the website in HTTPS while having share in the url. What should I do ? Thanks :)

Comment: From the machine running Share, can you use curl to call the /alfresco/s/index URL and see the result? If Alfresco and Share are on the same box use something like curl -uadmin:admin https://localhost/alfresco/s/index

Comment: Nope... I get the "Unable to forward this request... " error

Answer (score 0):

The alfresco.log / catalina.out should tell your more.
Where / how did you set up https? Have a a reverse proxy like nginx or apache in front of the alfresco tomcat?
If the log says something like "CSRF Token Filter issue" then you need to set  share.**host** / port / protocol in alfresco-global.properties as seen from the browser.